# Troubleshooting of low performance of console programs

Tags: terminal, performance, console

When I use neovim in alacritty in weston, it works slow (low FPS). However, this problem is observed only in this particular bunch of programs. There is no problem if:

- Running neovim in other terminal emulator (weston-terminal, for example);
- Running other programs in alacritty;
- Finally, nvim in alacritty works perfectly on my another computer.

How to track and understand the source of such a problem?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? You've asked a really broad question and not shown what you've already done.

Comment: The question is really wide, because I don't know where to start. The only thing I thought about is to build neovim myself and try to use the profiler. But is this the only way to debug such problem? If so, this will be the answer to my question.